# What is the best way to get coverage stats in cucumber js?

Tags: javascript, cucumberjs, istanbul, test-coverage, jscoverage

I'm designing my tests using the Behavior Driven Development (BDD) approach using [Gherkin](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/) syntax and running my tests with [Cucumber JS](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js).

I'm using [Cucumber Studio](https://studio.cucumber.io) to share reports and keep synced with my business stakeholders, and management.

Recently I needed to get test coverage reports for the project, and made some research but couldn't decide which library to use to get coverage reports and how.

So far I've found [JSCover](http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/), [Cucumber Reports](http://mkolisnyk.github.io/cucumber-reports/coverage-report), and [Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org) for test coverage reports, but I'm not sure how to use them exactly and which would be best for my case to use with Cucumber JS.

Comment: Are you tests run in a browser? (like karma or selenium) or is everything run inside node.js?

Comment: Actually currently they run on node executions, not on the browser directly. They include `unit`, `component`, `integration`, and `e2e` tests which don't require a browser to run. The most external test is E2E and it uses gRPC requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After several trials, I've figured out that it is pretty simple to use [Istanbul JS](https://istanbul.js.org/) to see code coverage.

I've followed the instructions on the website and install Istanbul's JavaScript library `nyc` using:

`yarn add -D nyc`

Then, I've updated my `scripts` in the `package.json` as the following:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cucumber-js ...",
    ...
    "coverage": "nyc yarn test"
  },
...
```

And when I run `yarn coverage` it runs the tests with wrapping by `nyc` and creating a coverage report as the following:

[image]

Comment: I believe you see the coverage (lines executed) in your test files, which is probably different from the results you expect - coverage of your application.

Comment: You are mentioning: all the files vs the `src` file difference, am I right?

Comment: If you want to use it without installing try `npx nyc yarn test`